# Trying to set hidden input's value to toggle between True and False in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, boolean

I am attempting to toggle the value of hidden inputs between true and false by users clicking on table cells. I am able to successfully assign event handlers to the cells, and get their values. My toggling function (`true_switch`) appears to always return false, however, and I can't be sure if it actually switches the values.

I would love it if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong? I had previously tried this using Boolean data-type variables, but I gave up on that because I wasn't sure how HTML value fields, and JavaScript's Boolean datatypes interact (I seemed to be getting false a lot, even when I expected true).

JavaScript:

```
var JS_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("JS")

for (y = 0; y < JS_elements.length; y++){
    x = JS_elements[y].getElementsByTagName("input")[0]

    JS_elements[y].addEventListener('click', function() {
        switch_JS(this);
    });
}

function true_switch(val) {
    document.getElementById("testblock").innerHTML +=  " ; true_switch worked "; <!-- debug line -->
    if (val = "true") {
        return "false"
    } else if (val = "false") {
        return "true"
    } else {
        alert("Error in the true_switch routine.")
    }
}

function switch_JS(domobj) {
    <!-- takes as input an HTML object, and switched the value from true to false, or from false to true -->
    val = domobj.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
    <!-- alert(val); -->
    document.getElementById("testblock").innerHTML = document.getElementById("testblock").innerHTML + " | Step 1 worked; "; <!-- debug line -->
    document.getElementById("testblock").innerHTML = document.getElementById("testblock").innerHTML +' ; val: ' + val + ' ; type: ' + typeof val + " ; true_switch(val): " + true_switch(val); <!-- debug line -->
    domobj.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = true_switch(val);
    document.getElementById("testblock").innerHTML = document.getElementById("testblock").innerHTML + " ; input value: " + domobj.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value; <!-- debug line -->
}
```

HTML:

```
<header>
        <hr>
            <p>- Header Background Color Controller -</p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Javascript Controller:</td>
                    <td class="JS">Red
                        <input type="hidden" value="true">
                    </td>
                    <td class="JS">Green
                        <input type="hidden" value="true">
                    </td>
                    <td class="JS">Blue
                        <input type="hidden" value="true">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>jQuery Controller:</td>
                    <td class="jQ" value=false>Red</td>
                    <td class="jQ" value=false>Green</td>
                    <td class="jQ" value=false>Blue</td>
                <tr>
            </table>
        <hr>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
if (val = "true") {
```

You're doing an assignment, rather than a comparison.  It should be:

```
if (val == "true") {
```

(and then the same for the comparison with `"false"`)

As an aside, a better way to perform debug logging is to use [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) and view the output in your browser's developer tools (usually F12 to open).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code of your example. The problems was a syntax errors, and most important the use of '=' instate of '==='. It is very important to use always '===' or '!==' in JavaScript.

main.js:

```
$(function () {
    var JS_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("JS"),
        testBlockElement = document.getElementById("testblock");

    for (var y = 0, len = JS_elements.length; y < len; y++) {
        var x = JS_elements[y].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

        JS_elements[y].addEventListener('click', function () {
            switch_JS(this);
        });
    }

    function true_switch(val) {
        testBlockElement.innerHTML += " ; true_switch worked ";
        <!-- debug line -->
        if (val === "true") {
            return "false";
        } else if (val === "false") {
            return "true";
        } else {
            alert("Error in the true_switch routine.");
        }
    }

    function switch_JS(domobj) {
        <!-- takes as input an HTML object, and switched the value from true to false, or from false to true -->
        var val = domobj.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
        testBlockElement.innerHTML += " | Step 1 worked; ";
        <!-- debug line -->
        testBlockElement.innerHTML += ' ; val: ' + val + ' ; type: ' + typeof val + " ; true_switch(val): " + true_switch(val);
        <!-- debug line -->
        domobj.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = true_switch(val);
        testBlockElement.innerHTML += " ; input value: " + domobj.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value + '<br />';
        <!-- debug line -->
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <hr>
    <p>- Header Background Color Controller -</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Javascript Controller:</td>
            <td class="JS">Red
                <input type="hidden" value="true">
            </td>
            <td class="JS">Green
                <input type="hidden" value="true">
            </td>
            <td class="JS">Blue
                <input type="hidden" value="true">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>jQuery Controller:</td>
            <td class="jQ">Red</td>
            <td class="jQ">Green</td>
            <td class="jQ">Blue</td>
        <tr>
    </table>

    <div id="testblock"></div>
</header>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```